# 'npm start' error in ubuntu,but it's ok in windows 7

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, express, npm

How can I find the problem and fix it? Here is the error message:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! aa-server@1.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the aa-server@1.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the aa-server package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs aa-server
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls aa-server
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /aa-server/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Does the `.bin` directory in your project contain `www` on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes,it works when i use "node bin/www".

Comment: That's odd, running it directly works? If so, could you post your full `npm-debug.log`?

Comment: sorry,i forgot to reply you,i don't know what i did before,the server has been normalized.^^